# Transpose a fixed number of cells from multiple rows to a single column in Excel

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

How can I transpose a fixed number of cells from multiple rows to a single column in VBA?
For example: first 10 cells (columns A-J) from rows 1-50 into column A of a different worksheet.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to receive the most effective help here. Specifically, let us know what you tried and where it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a `10x10` range in the first worksheet stating from `A1`.

```
k=1
for i = 1 to 10
   for j = 1 to 10
      range(i,j).copy
      workbooks("wb2").sheets("ws").Range(k,1).pastespecial xlValues
      k= k+1
   next
next
```

not: I dont have excel in pc I currently work on, so it is not tested.